# Deploying a contract web3 error: invalid argument 0: missing 0x prefix for hex data

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, raw-transaction

This is my raw transaction:

> {
>     "nonce": "0x0",
>     "gasPrice": "0x2540be4000",
>     "gasLimit": "0x493e0",
>     "data": "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",
>     "from": "0xad4d5b5be2d68b4c4c2e1c4bc5e85d86d8b2a5dc"
>   }

I'm stuck getting the error:
Error: invalid argument 0: missing 0x prefix for hex data

I have seen similar examples and I don't know what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in the raw transaction:

I'm serializing using ethereumjs-tx, and the problem was that '0x' is not added automatically after Tx.serialize